# How to PASS data using Core Data among THREE ViewControllers on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, segue

I have a project on Xcode using Core Data (storyboard and ARC, it's Xcode 5, iOS 7)
So, the thing is I got three ViewControllers

> > ### 1) A `TableViewController` displaying a list of objects.
> >
> > ### 2) A `ViewController1` displaying several `textFields` for getting information from the user.
> >
> > ### 3) Another `ViewController2` displaying several `textViews` non-editable of calculations made of the information obtained in the `ViewController1`

In the first ViewController you have two ways of going to the second one.

> > #### 1) Updating an existing object, when the user press an existing cell in the tableView.
> >
> > #### 2) Creating a new object.

My problem resides when I create a new one.

I have nothing to pass when I intent to create a new object, so, in the preparation for segue I don't send anything.

Once in the `ViewController1`, I have this code to SAVE the data obtained from the text fields:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectContext *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Object" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [newSiembra setValue:self.nombreTF.text forKey:@"nombre"];
    [newSiembra setValue:self.datosTF.text forKey:@"datos"];


    NSError *error = nil;

    //save the object in the persistent store
    if (![_context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

If I want to display the value for the key `"datos"` in a `text view` in the `ViewController2`, I will need to pass the data in a preparation for segue.

### How do I pass the object that I just created to the `ViewController2` ?

In my `ViewController2.h` I could have:

```
    @property (strong) NSManagedObject *object;
```

Attempting to receive the recently created object in the `ViewController1` into the property `object` which belongs to the `ViewController2`

### So in the `-(void)preparationForSegue` in the `ViewController1` I should have:

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {  
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"2"])
        {

        ViewController2 *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.object = ???????????

        }
    }
```

Please, if you can, complete my code replacing the question marks.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach for creating new objects is to have a UITableView with a fetchedResultsController and when you click the + button your code creates a new object which appears in the UITableView.  Usually one would use a default name like "New Folder" or something.

The user then selects the object and goes to the detailed view.

Alternately when you click the + button create the new object and programatically select it and and set up the viewController2 passing in the newly created object.  At the same time you would set the viewController2.item property to the newly created object so that it can display the results of any changes to attributes on the item object.

I don't know how you are observing changes to attributes but I assume you are registering for notifications and then updating the UI if the objects attributes get changed.

Have a look at the sample app here that allows you to create new objects and then select the new object and go to a detailed view.  Post additional questions if I misunderstood your question.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/